# checking string reply against a list

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a bit of code that is going to communicate with a beamer. I can ask what the current selected input is and will then get a reply in the form of:

```
RG1
RG2
VID
etc...
```

Now I can make a long list of if statements that check against all possible reply but I already have all these replies in a list cause I use the same commands to set the input. What would be a good way of checking if the reply string against that list?

Comment: Do you want `"RG1" in name_list`?

Comment: @And I want to check if the current input is the input that I want it to be. Thanks to you guys I came up with:
`if Data in Power:
        if Data != powerstatus: SetPower(powerstatus)
    
    if Data in inputsource:
        if Data != inputstatus: SetInput(inputstatus)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if something is in a list you can use `in` instead of using an `if` statement to check for every possibility in the list.

```
 >>> a_list =['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
 >>> 'str1' in a_list
 ...
 True
```